# What XML schema dataType is space efficient for binary data?

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm creating an XML schema and need to include some fields of raw binary data.  What built-in datatype offers the most space efficient representation?  I see `base64Binary` and `hexBinary` as two possibilities but they both appear to be string representations of hexadecimal codes and thus not space efficient and also incur a time penalty to encode them. What built-in datatype would offer me the best space and time efficient representation of my binary data?

Comment: Perhaps EXI, a binary representation of XML, would be useful ((http://www.w3.org/TR/exi/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no other types out of the box that deal with binary content.

The most efficient is base64, with around a 30% overhead; hex is at least twice the size. It is also assumed that you're using a predominantly single byte-character set such as utf-8. Encoding XML using utf-16 will see the above numbers double.

The advantage of using these built in types pays off with typical xml to code bindings libraries; for e.g. JAXB will give you a byte[], so encoding/decoding is tranparent to you.

It also depends on how you move/store your XML; if you use a SOAP based serializer with support for binary attachments, then particularly for large sets, it pays off to go down this route.